# h:outputFormat with f:param and internationalization

Tags: jsf, internationalization

Ok, this seems pretty wired to me. I´ve got this simple piece of jsf code:

```
<h:outputFormat id="idOutput"
              value="#{msgs.mymessage}"
              styleClass="standard"
              escape="false">
<f:param id="idLogoutParam" value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

'msgs' simply gets a string from a property file in webApplicationContext. mymessage is:

```
"please click <a href="{0}">here</a>"
```

for english locale and

```
"klicken Sie bitte <a href="{0}">hier</a>. "
```

for german users. For german localization everything is working fine. But using an english version of any browser (ok, at least ff and chrome) will reslult in showing up something like 
"%7B0%7D" or"{0}" instead of using the property´s value.

I´m using JSF 1.1_02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the decisive point in my question.
The localized messages where longer than I posted. In the english version I used the
' sign. 
I didn´t knew I´m not allowed to use it in outputFormat with parameter.